# How to search data QSqlTableModel, Qtableview from QlineEdit with the help of QcomboBox?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel, qsqltablemodel

I am using QSqlTableModel, (FilterProxyModel) as custom proxy modelwith QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel, QTableView,Qcombobox.

```
self.lineEdit       = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
self.view           = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
self.comboBox       = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
```

Below code is the custom filter class to get  menu of Columns from tableview :

```
class FilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._filter_value = None

    @property
    def filter_value(self):
        return self._filter_value

    @filter_value.setter
    def filter_value(self, value):
        self._filter_value = value
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        if self.filter_value is None:
            return True
        value = (
            self.sourceModel()
            .index(sourceRow, self.filterKeyColumn(), sourceParent)
            .data(self.filterRole())
        )
        return value == self.filter_value
```

Below is the database model:

```
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("model.db")
    db.open()

    self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
    self.model.setTable("sheet")
    self.model.select()
    self.view.setModel(self.model)

    self.proxy = FilterProxyModel(self)###
    self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

    self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
```

Below is the details of my question

```
    column_names = (["All","Name", "Age", "Adress"])
    self.comboBox.addItems([x for x in column_names])


@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def msa_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
    self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
    self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
    self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
    search = QtCore.QRegExp(    text,
                                QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                )

    self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)
```

for example : I tryied with above function with QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp its showing the data in first column, selected "all" in Qcombobox.

I added items "All","Name", "Age", and "Adress" in the combobox, and I am trying to search or filter data from QlineEdit with using of QcomboBox as if I select "All" in cobobox and when I am typing words in QlineEdit that should be filter data from all columns.

If I select "Name" or "Age", or "Adress" on QcomboBox that should be filter data as per the column name selection in the Qcombobox. My database have String and as well as Int Values. Are there any examples available for this?

[image]

Comment: I have a question: The code you use is from my previous answer in that it is intended for all types of data, for example the "age" column is integers, how do you want to apply a regex for numbers?

Comment: @eyllanesc. I do not know. I tried. is there any way?

Comment: My question is not to ask you if you can or not, but to reflect on your requirement.

Comment: @eyllanesc.Yes as per your previous Answer integer values also are there.

Comment: @eyllanesc.The data base also same. or do you need me share the database.

Comment: @eyllanesc. How to inherit all properties from parent filter to customize filter along with customized properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`filterKeyColumn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterKeyColumn-prop) properly:

> This property holds the column where the key used to filter the contents of the source model is read from.
>
> The default value is 0. If the value is -1, the keys will be read from all columns.

So you can connect both the `textChanged` signal of the line edit *and* `currentIndexChanged` of the combo to the function, then set the filter accordingly:

```
def msa_lineEdit_textChanged(self):
    search = QtCore.QRegExp(self.lineEdit.text(), 
        QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive, QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp)
    self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(self.combo.currentIndex() - 1)
    self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)
```

Note that your custom proxy won't work as expected if you're using `setFilterRegExp` and that's because you have overridden the `filterAcceptsRow` method.

You should change the implementation like this:

```
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        if self.filter_value is None:
            return super().filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent)
        if self.filterKeyColumn() >= 0:
            value = (
                self.sourceModel()
                .index(sourceRow, self.filterKeyColumn(), sourceParent)
                .data(self.filterRole())
            )
            return value == self.filter_value
        for column in range(self.columnCount()):
            value = (
                self.sourceModel()
                .index(sourceRow, column, sourceParent)
                .data(self.filterRole())
            )
            if value == self.filter_value:
                return True
        return False
```

You should also clear the property whenever the regex filter is applied:

```
    def setFilterRegExp(self, filter):
        self.filter_value = None
        super().setFilterRegExp(filter)
```

Comment: I added your answer and used "self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.msa_lineEdit_textChanged)". It is not responding when i am typing on Qlineedit.

Comment: Is custom filter "class FilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):"  effects "self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)" ? I do not know.

Comment: @musicamante.As per your Note new instance of the proxy should not to be made every time. so how to call original "QSortFilterProxyModel" into "def msa_lineEdit_textChanged(self):"  function. Along with custom FilterProxyModel which is used above.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. And I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but if you're still using the pyqtSlot decorator, remove it: as you can see, I didn't use it, and slot decorators are rarely a requirement for signal/slot connections.

Comment: @musicamante.I removed  pyqtSlot decorator still not working.  And What i want to say: I am using customized filter as "self.proxy = FilterProxyModel" that you can find in the top of my question, that was used to create QMenu.

Comment: @musicamante.Actually if i make a new instance of the proxy to "msa_lineEdit_textChanged" function as  "self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)" that your code is working. But you said that don't make new instance of the proxy each time.

Comment: *What* is not working? Be more specific! Is the `msa_lineEdit_textChanged` function called? If not, check the connection and the output of the program in the shell/prompt to look for more debugging info. Is it called? Then, first of all ensure that it works for a specific column, if that's so, you have to implement the filterAcceptsRow correctly, so that it checks for *all* columns if the setFilterKeyColumn is -1, otherwise you'll obviously get invalid indexes.

Comment: From the shell there is no error and at the same time  the function is idle. If you want my full code i can share with you.

Comment: @musicamante.I  have a doubt that is : Is custom filter prevent parent instance or properties? Why i am asking this because   "self.proxy = FilterProxyModel" was customized. And " self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(self.combo.currentIndex() - 1)", "
    self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search) " are not responding.

Comment: If you call `setFilterRegExp` on your custom model and `filter_value` is not set, the result is that there will be no filtering at all (as the implementation of `filterAcceptsRow` returns `True` in that case). See the update.

Comment: (you should probably remove the new question you just posted, as the update should solve the issue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219493/discussion-between-user3030327-and-musicamante).